# Conformity vs. complexity (gamepad/controller layout)

Tags: controls, windows-os, complexity

I'm porting a VR app to non-VR. In VR you can move your head to look around, which you can't in a Windows app of course. This means that I also have to change the controller layout. Users might use both versions of the app or maybe only one of them.

**Old layout:**

[image: Old layout]

- Left analog stick: Move
- Press left analog stick: Toggle run
- Right analog stick: Fly up/down
- Left/right buttons: Switch between 3D models (previous one, next one)
- Left/right triggers: Switch between extra 3D models (displayed additional to the other ones)
- The D-pad and A, B, X and Y are all used for special functions (like: "Y" resets your position)

**New layout:**

- Left analog stick: Move
- Press left analog stick: Toggle run
- Right analog stick: Look around

*Version 1 (Blue: Differs from original):*

[image: New layout version 1]

- Right button/right trigger: Switch to next model
- Left button/left trigger: Fly up/down
- Advantage: Less complex, the D-pad and the other buttons keep the same special functions
- Disadvantages: No way to go back to the previous model, so not conform with the old app; I've never seen anyone use the left button/trigger to jump/crouch/fly, so possibly not as intuitive

*Version 2 (Blue: Differs from original):*

[image: New layout version 2]

- Left/right button & left/right triggers: Switch between models (previous and next)
- A and B: Fly up/down
- Press right analog stick (with indicator on the screen): Switch between movement and special functions (A, B, X and Y are each mapped twice)
- Advantage: You can go back to the previous model, so it's more conform with the old app; more available buttons; also more conform with commonly used key bindings (A: Jump, B: crouch)
- Disadvantages: More complex because you have to switch to access all functions

As you can see, there are advantages and disadvantages for both versions and I'm not sure what to do here: Is it better to go with something that's less complex but also less conform with a previous version or something that's more conform but also more complex?

Driving a car in a game and controlling your character usually use the same controls or at least very similar controls but that's different "modes", so is it common to map buttons twice with some kind of additional "mode switch" button while you're still in the same game "mode"?

Comment: I think a screenshot or mockup would really help with this question :)

Comment: It would be easier for us to grasp the logic fully if you used a pictures of a controller and wrote each action on/beside the buttons. Then we could visually compare them instead of having to imagine each detail.

Comment: I added a couple of pictures. Text written in blue means that it differs from the original controller layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a gamepad layout that is both conform with the old one but also easy to learn, while still providing controls for the new features, so I ended up doing this:

Layout 1 (less complex but not as conform) is going to be the default layout, so older users should have an easier time getting used to the new version of my app.

There's also going to be a way to switch to layout 2 (more complex but also more conform to the old layout/gaming standards) in the options (this choice will be saved and restored on startup), which in turn shouldn't be a problem for younger users (/gamers).

Answer (score 2):

I think that it depends more on the users' learning cost. Your users have already formed their behavior customs and cognitive of your app's function system.

So for your question :

> Is it better to go with something that's less complex but also less conform with a previous version or something that's more conform but also more complex?

I prefer the later one. Because it's easier for users to adapt to a new version. However, the former one is a next-step-goal. I suggest that you can gradually iterate the functions layout in new versions based on every latest old version.

BTW, it will be more visual to give answers if you attach some prototypes :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree with you because I prefer using the standard gaming layouts myself (so "A"=jump/up and "B"=crouch/down, LB/LT just feel weird to me) and I'm also trying to use gaming standards as much as possible. Most of the users of my app aren't gamers though and they might not have used/may never use the old version at all (the new version won't replace the old). Since version 1 was suggested by someone else partially involved in the development (a non-gamer), I don't want to disregard it right away but also want to find the best solution for most users.

Comment: Once I've got a set layout I don't want to change it again (unless there are new functions) and changing it over time would be counterproductive. If you've got a different suggestion, I'd be happy to look at it. ;) Sorry, there are no prototypes, I've only got an old controller image that I can't post here. I hope that it's still clear enough what's what.

Comment: There are two factors to be concerned. User amount and industry customs.

Comment: 1. **User amount**. Consider your user amount currently, a huge one could be decisive. Because it means lots of your target users have already formed using customs. On the other hand, if a much larger user amount matches your team goal or is predictable in the sooner future, then I think better offer a more simple and less complex version for your users, and conformity might be second to be considered.

Comment: 2. **Industry customs**. Are their many similar apps to yours in the market? If yes, then I think a new version layout should be designed based on industry customs, which might shape people's habit preference. hope that I catch your words. For your reference :)

Comment: 1. The app isn't openly accessible and probably will never be, so the user amount is limited. I don't know if the new version will have more users than the old - like I said, it's possible that some will use the old version, some the new and some both. It just depends on personal preference, I guess (one's VR, the other isn't), since the setup for both versions is about the same in difficulty. 2. No, there are no apps like it afaik. The users are both younger and older people, so using gaming standards already covers the former but making it easy for the latter at the same time is the problem.

Comment: OK, I see :)  I think you already have an appropriate choice in mind. Happy for the discussion~~~

Comment: That's the thing, I don't. Personally I prefer version 2 because it's closer to what I'm used to but it's a more complex solution older users might have a problem with. These older users usually don't game, so any easy-ish solution (that makes at least a little bit sense) should work for them but at the same time this easy solution (version 1) clashes with the old version of the app and gaming standards, so what the younger users are used to. In the end it's back to my original question: Should you rather go complex and conform with an older version or less complex but not conform.

Comment: I personally prefer version 2 for this moment. First, version 1 allows not to go back to the previous model. If this function is important, it should be kept. Second, it **is** a little bit weird to use the left button/trigger to jump/crouch/fly haha. And for version 2, it's easier to learn while more complex using special functions. But I think it's OK if special functions are not used frequently. In addition, I guess that doesn't cost a lot press right analog stick and [A, B, X, Y] at the same time to switch?

Comment: However, we can't easily draw a conclusion based on speculation. We all agree that the new version should be easy to learn and follow users' mental model(Big_Chair also mentioned). Then a user research or usibility test of two versions might help. And when you publish a new version, your users can learn the differences though a functions guide :)

Comment: It is important to switch models and while it's not that vital to be able to go back I still added that feature in the old version because I know how frustrating it is in games to switch between abilities with a single button but you accidently skip the one you want and then you have to go through the whole list again. No, it's not right stick + button but "press right stick to switch mode" and then the different functions are active until you press the stick again. I think pressing the stick and the buttons at the sime time isn't that good because usually you use your thumb for all of them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misunderstood. It’s difficult to press them at the same time. Thumb is used for almost all the operations. Well then is switching modes frequently needed?

Comment: I think that flying around is used more often than the extra functions (check my answer to Big_Chairs' post below).

Answer (score 1):

**Short version:** Skip to "Questions to help you decide".

---

**Long version:**

As most things in UX, such a question is very dependant on context and user group.

I think in this case the most important question is **how often are the different actions used?**
Because in the end this determines how the user's workflow with your app will look like.

Imagine if you choose version 3 with different modes but users have to switch modes constantly. It would drive them crazy. On the other hand, if the switch happens rarely, they'd be glad to have room for more actions. So you should always keep your user's workflow in mind when making design choices.

Danlin Chen already mentioned the **cost of learning**, this is also supported by this NN Group article:
[Don’t Prioritize Efficiency Over Expectations](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/efficiency-vs-expectations/)

> Summary: Features meant to increase user efficiency by reducing steps can end up hurting users if they do not conform to existing mental models and expectations based on past experiences.

But in the same article they point out that [design standards are not intended to stifle creativity](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/do-interface-standards-stifle-design-creativity/):

> Standards ensure a consistent vocabulary, but don't limit designers' freedom (and responsibility) in deeper design issues.

(You could also argue that they already have to re-learn the flying control for the new version, might as well let them re-learn something else on the way.)

In the end it is a trade-off between learning cost and possibly easier controls. **And you have to decide based on what you know about your users.** Because after all, your top priority should be to make their life as easy as possible with your app.

---

**Questions to help you decide:**
Ask yourself (or even better, your users!), how often do they need to fly up or down and how often do they need to use the special functions. Would it be annoying for them to have to switch between these modes?
Then pick version 1.

On the other hand, how important is the switching between models for them? Are there a lot of models, so that the user would be very frustrated by having to go through the whole list again if he missed his target?
Pick version 2.

Or you could ask your users and maybe adapt your design even further.

Comment: My app is about looking at the models (can be 1-2 or 10), so while the extra functions that I currently use A/B/X/Y for (e.g. save model, restore/delete saved models) are important, being able to fly around properly is too and will properly happen a lot more often than e.g. saving models. I know that giving too many choices can turn into bad design but is adding both controllers layouts and simply letting the user pick one (includes saving the choice of course) okay in my case? E.g. make version 1 the default for older users and the younger users know how to switch to the other one anyway.

Comment: @Neph I think the caution about too many choices does not apply when you only have 2. Giving them a choice might actually be a good idea, since "Flexibility and efficiency of use" is part of [N&N's 10 Heuristics for UI design](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/)

Comment: @Neph Consider marking one of the answers as accepted or writing your own solution as an answer, so future users can quickly see what the optimal solution to that question was

Comment: Okay, that's good then, thanks. But still, while I know what layout to use now, I'm still not sure what of my original question is more desireable. I know that it depends on context, so: There are both older and younger users and they've all used the old version of the app. It doesn't even matter what the new layouts exactly look like, let's just say that one is more complex but rather conform with the old layout and the other is less complex but also less conform. Which one should you go for then with that mixed target group? Or should the choice always be: Add both, then let the user pick?

Comment: @Neph I think the first choice is always: make one idea so user friendly (with user testing) that everyone can live with it. If that is not possible (because of different needs of different sub-groups of users), **then** use different versions and let the users pick.